# Change spacing between words in LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

The question is simple.

How can I change the space between words in LibreOffice?

Something like this (from *InDesign*):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such option exists for word spacing in Libre Office. You can expand the character spacing, but this would also expand the characters, not just the spaces between words.

From [taming-openoffice-org.com](http://www.taming-openoffice-org.com/newsite/?page_id=84):

> On the Position tab of the Paragraph Style dialog, in the Spacing section, select Expanded spacing and the amount of space to be inserted between characters. You may need to experiment a bit to find the best spacing for the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: In LibreOffice 5.2.1.2 on Mac OS 10.11.6, that option *does* control spacing between words, not spacing between characters.  Which is ironic, because what *I* need is character spacing, not word spacing.

Comment: (Correction to my previous comment; it does control character spacing, however the effect on word spacing is far out of proportion to the effect on characters within a word.)

Answer (score 0):

You can replace ' ' (single space) with '  ' (Double space). Not a neat idea but still works. At least for me.

Comment: This worked for me as well.